# Get count of most repeated letter in a word

Tags: javascript, hashtable

I am trying to get the count of the most repeated letter in a word

```
function GreatestCount(str)
{
    var count = {}

    for (var i = 0 ; i<str.length;i++)
    {
        var char = str[i];
        count[char] = (count[char] || 0) + 1;

    }

     //get the largest number for the letter counts
    var max = 0;

    for (var c in count) {
        if (count[c] > max) max = count[c];
    }

    return max
}
```

can someone explain to me why

```
count[char] = (count[char] || 0) + 1;// this works

count[char] += 1 // this does not work
```

Comment: @Oriol already answered your question, but i would like to help u abit more. u can store the max while inserting to the object, that will reduce the last 'for' there, saves 26 loops. in Addition, you need to use .ToLowerCase to prevent counting the same letter in different counters. for example 'a' and 'A' will act differently unless you do this.

Answer (score 7):

Because

```
count[char] += 1
```

is equal to

```
count[char] = count[char] + 1
```

and the first time the code is run, `count[char]` is `undefined` so it's pretty much the same as

```
undefined + 1 // which is NaN
```

The working version circumvents this case by safely adding with `0` using `||` operator.

Answer (score 5):

Initially, `count` is an empty object<sup>†</sup>, so it doesn't have the `char` property. Therefore, `count[char]` returns `undefined`.

And `undefined + 1` produces `NaN`.

Therefore, you must inititialize it to `0` in order to make it work properly.

<sup>†: `count` is not really an empty object because it inherits properties from `Object.prototype`. It would be problematic if a `char` property is defined there. I recommend using `count = Object.create(null)` instead.</sup>

Comment: nothing else to add, to my opinion this question is answered.

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialize your **count[char]** to zero before incrementing it.

Answer (score 2):

On first occurrence `count[char]` is undefined and `undefined += 1 !== 1`

Answer (score 0):

As other said your variable is not initialize in the beginning
so count[char] +=1 is not working, but when you do (count[char] || 0) you actually tell them that you want to set 0 if the variable is "false". False could mean undefined, NaN, 0.